# Dynamic Snapshot Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, snapshot

I have a time differences function that gets a **date** and calculates it differences with the current time and return time differences like:

`4 days ago`

Now, I used this function on a web page with some Unit test and Snapshot test.
Snapshot testing will fail every day because tomorrow the differences will be `5 days ago`

What can I do in this situation?

Update: put my pseudo code

```
const timeDiff = gTime => {
    return (currentTime - gtime) 
};
```

This function will invoke in my web page, components, comment section and ...
so all my component's snapshot test will fail.

Comment: You don't test against the actual time. Time is a *dependency*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, time is a dependency but this function is on my comment component and other components that cause failure to snapshot testing for all pages that contain this time diff function.

Comment: Then you're not handling that dependency correctly. Again, *don't test against the actual time*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is an independent function that calculates this dynamic data
I can't remove all snapshot tests that use this function.

Comment: But you can replace it with a test double or, as the answer below suggests, mock out time itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as this is not my solution, I update the post with my code.

Comment: How does that help illustrate anything? Where does `currentTime` come from? Why can't you replace it for testing purposes? Why can't you replace `timeDiff` *entirely* when testing the components?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198575/discussion-between-novonimo-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally I found the answer.
I use a third-party library for time manipulations. I used this library inside of my react component ( consider import in a js file).

So I couldn't mock the data for this library.

eventually, I decided to **remove** the import of this third-library from my file, and passe a function (known as props in react.js) to my component.

Now I can easily pass a mock data to this component and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the `Date` object so it always returns the same time.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#2-tests-should-be-deterministic

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Comment: This is a miss conception. I use mocking data but the problem will still exist. 
because of my function will calculate the current time that will change every second!!!

Comment: Mocking the `Date` object means replacing it with a version you control before your tests run and your function is called, and then replacing it with the original version afterwards. Your function thinks its calling a normal `Date` object to get the current time, but it's really calling a custom `Date` that always returns the same current time value statically always. This is a very common issue with the snapshot testing, so much so they mention it specially in the Jest docs. Read the first link I added above :)

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is not my answer. 
I know that time and date are changes in every second and I must mock them.

My question is something else. This function imported to my component ( in ReactJS) 

and it's not a prop that I can change it from the outer side and mock it in test file.

Comment: Are you getting mocks confused with dependency injection? You can mock functions so that when they are imported into your component file they're replaced by a function you supply https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Answer (score 1):

You may have 2 options:

1- consider if you had a null input (or something like that), in this scenario what would your component return, so by changing your function you can give your function a null input and expect to get an expected result.

```
const timeDiff = gTime => {
    if(!gTime) return "";
    return (currentTime - gtime)  };   

// ------------test---------------

timeDiff(null)
```

2- give an input that will return an expected result, for example in your scenario you could give current time as input (as mock data) so every time you will get a 0-second difference in your result.

```
const timeDiff = gTime => {
    return (currentTime - gtime) 
};

// ------------test---------------

mockData = getCurrentTime()
timeDiff(mockData)
```